# Type casting an RLMObject throws away data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have code that saves an RLMObject subclass to the realm database. This code works and I have used the realm browser to verify that it is saved as expected.

I then want to query the realm database for this object that I saved, and I want to cast it to the RLMObject subclass that is was before I saved it.

Here is the code:

```
let queryResults = RealmSubclass.allObjects()

for result in queryResults {
    if result is RealmSubclass {
        let temp = result as RealmSubclass
        println(temp.name)
        println(temp.dateOfBirth)
        println(temp.gender)
    }
}
```

When I check the values in the debug console, using print object, I see values that I expect. However, when I do a type cast to `RealmSubclass` the resulting object has no correct values, only nil values.

Why could this be? I have read the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/#queries), to no avail.

**EDIT**:
Here is the RLMObject subclass:

```
public class RealmSubclass: RLMObject {
    public dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
    public dynamic var name: String = ""
    public dynamic var dateOfBirth: NSDate = NSDate()
    public dynamic var gender: NSString = Consts.Gender.Male

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that the values were actually being returned. What happened is that Swift debugging is not up to standard yet. The debug area was showing incorrect information.

Comment: What's failing in your example isn't Swift debugging, it's the dynamic cast to RealmSubclass. No data is being lost or thrown away.